# Does java provide any way to detect corrupted UDP segments?

Tags: java, networking, udp

So I making a simple network game, in which I will be using UDP segments.

I have a couple of questions to ask:

1. Does java detect or provide the means to know that a segment has
   been corrupted?
2. If not how can I check whether a segment is
   corrupted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java by itself has nothing to generically detect a corrupt UDP segment. UDP has an (optional) checksum which is checked by the OS and any segments where the checksum is wrong will be dropped and not be delivered to the application in the first place. In case of UDP this means that such a segment gets simply lost from the perspective of the application. Note that this will not detect every possible error but only the more common ones like a single bit flip.

If the application needs more than this it is to be explicitly implemented at the application level, for example by using a HMAC.